# Python Based DNS traffic Sniffer

Tags: python, networking, dns, network-programming, sniffing

I am trying to write the DNS packet sniffer in python to capture information whenever NXdomain packet is found e.g Response code, query, transport protocol used, dest port, authorative name server.

First of all, I don't know where to start with. I watched some of the tutorials on youtube but most of them are sniffing ethernet frames and try to get information from (IP/ARP frame) within the ethernet frame but this information is useless for me as I want to capture DNS information by sniffing DNS packet.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Two issues: first, you'll need to access the packets; second, you'll need to provide some code, or this question will likely be closed either because answers will be opinion-based or that the question isn't specific enough. No reflection on you, that's just the way SO works.

Comment: Also, see https://pypi.org/project/dnspython/ - that will likely do all the record handling you need.

Comment: Yes, i have sniffed the packets, but the information  that I want to get is not there in the ethernet frame packet. So, I am seeking help to approach the problem in a right way. e.g Where is the dns packet is located? How do I get this DNS packet? Secondly the library you have mentioned cannot used for sniffing. Using this library "dnspython" we can just resolve the domain names into their respective IP's by specifying host name which is not the case in Sniffing sense!

Answer (score 0):

In the case of (most current) DNS traffic it will be carried as the payload of UDP datagrams, which are themselves carried as the payload of Internet Protocol datagrams, and it is those datagrams that are carried inside the Ethernet frames.

I presume you are familiar with Ethernet frame formats, and understand that the payload starts (assuming you do mean Ethernet, and not 802.3) after 14 bytes of header. The IPv4 datagram also uses a fixed-length header, this time of 20 bytes, but may also include so-called options.

The UDP protocol uses a very simple 16-byte header.

So if you want to take a quick guess, frames with no IP options will have the DNS packet starting after (16+20+16) == 52 bytes of lower-level headers. If you want to handle *all* packets, you'll have to learn how to compute the length of IP headers with options.

The `dnspython` library is worth investigating, as it is capable of [converting bytestreams into DNS messages](https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/message-make.html#dns.message.from_wire), which are a very convenient way to access the DNS packet information.

There is no code in this answer since there is no code in your question. Perhaps you can follow up with a new question in which you should failing code you have actually tried - that would give answerers a but nore to work on.